# How to turn set Cache-Control using ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack, cache-control

I want to turn off caching for my HTTP responses.  Here's my code:

`public class CacheControlHeaderAttribute : ResponseFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object responseDto)
        {
            res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.CacheControl, "no-store,must-revalidate,no-cache,max-age=0");
            res.AddHeader("X-Test", "Hello from ServiceStack!");
        }
    }`

The problem is that it doesn't work.  Cache-Control is getting set to **private**.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly opt-in for [HTTP Caching in ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-caching) which doesn't cache or add the HTTP Cache-Control header by default so I'm assuming it's being added by your Web Server which you'll want to look at configuring instead.

Otherwise adding HTTP Headers can be added using any of the options listed in [Customize HTTP Responses](https://docs.servicestack.net/customize-http-responses).

But if it's not being returned something else fronting your App (e.g. Web Server / Proxy) is using their own Cache-Control headers.